# What is the most elegant way to implement the requirements below if there is no multiple inheritance in javascript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype, es6-class

The system produces log records of 2 types:
LogsA and LogsB.
Write js function to create a record of type LogsC
from list of records of type logs_A and logs_B

logs_A:{
m_id: string
time: number
level: info|warning|error
msg: string
}

logs_B:
{
id: string
m_id:string
m_name:string
}

logs_C: {
m_id: string
timestamp: number
level: string
details: string
}

requirements:

1. join on m_id
2. details field in type C is combination of B.module_name + ' ' + A.msg
3. delete records of level in
4. sort by timestamp

Comment: I don't see how multiple inheritance would make this problem easier. You could probably solve this - if you needed to do these joins and such in javascript - using simple for loops and Maps.

Comment: Start by writing a function `pairs(A, B)` which creates a list of all possible pairs from A and B ("cartesian product"). `filter` out pairs where primary keys do not match. `map` the result to produce the desired structure. Good luck!